# How to convert a single dimension array to a multi dimension array with one column in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an algorithm that predicts values

when the labels are multi-label it returns a multi-D array

### example

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TestSize, random_state=42)

>>> y_test
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)

>>> y_test.shape
(100, 20)

mdl.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_hat = mdl.predict(X_test)
```

in this case the outcome is multi-D array

```
>>> y_hat
array([[0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)

>>> y_hat.shape
(100, 20)
```

This is good, and no issues here

but when I work with a single label

such as this example

### example

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TestSize, random_state=42)

>>> y_test
array([[1],
       [0],
       [0],
       ...,
       [1],
       [0],
       [1]], dtype=uint8)


>>> y_test.shape
(100, 1)

mdl.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_hat = mdl.predict(X_test)
```

in this case **y_test** is multi-D array with 1 column *(100, 1)*

but **y_hat** is a single dimension array *(100,)*

```
>>> y_hat
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       ...
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=uint8)

>>> y_hat.shape
(100,)
```

How can I convert **y_hat** to a multi-D array with 1 column *(100, 1)*
only when **y_hat** is not the same dimension as **y_test**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly used methods include slicing and reshaping:

```
>>> ar
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> ar[:, np.newaxis]    # ar[:, None]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
>>> ar.reshape(-1, 1)    # ar.reshape(*ar.shape, 1)
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

However, this will only create a new array view and will not modify the original array. If you want to modify the original array, you can directly assign a value to the `shape` *property* of array:

```
>>> ar
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> ar.shape = -1, 1
>>> ar
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

Where, -1 means that the size of this dimension is calculated by numpy itself. It is usually obtained by dividing the length of the array by the size of other dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically convert to 2D **only if needed**, you can use [`numpy.atleast_2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html):

```
a = np.random.randint(0,2,100)
a.shape
# (100,)

a = np.atleast_2d(a.T).T
a.shape
# (100, 1)
```